Why does my Replit deployment work in Webview but fail to load on the production domain?
I am deploying a web application on Replit using a Reserved VM deployment. While the app works perfectly in the Replit Webview (on ports like 3000 and 3001), it fails to load on the production domain (e.g., https://my-app.replit.app).
Context:

My .replit configuration includes the following:
[deployment]
run = ["npm", "start"]
deploymentTarget = "gce"

[[ports]]
localPort = 80
externalPort = 3000

[[ports]]
localPort = 3000
externalPort = 3001

[[ports]]
localPort = 3001
externalPort = 3002

[[ports]]
localPort = 5173
externalPort = 80
exposeLocalhost = true

[[ports]]
localPort = 8080
externalPort = 8080



My frontend uses Vite, and the vite.config.ts has:
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
});


My backend (Python) runs on port 8080:
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)


According to Replit's documentation for Reserved VM deployments:

HTTP requests are sent to external port 80.

The server must listen on 0.0.0.0 (not 127.0.0.1).

Port auto-detection will use the first opened port unless explicitly configured.




Issues:

The app works in development but fails on the production domain.

Logs suggest the backend is running, but requests to the production domain do not connect to the app.

I suspect an issue with port mapping or traffic routing between frontend and backend



What I've tried:

Configuring PORT=8080 and host=0.0.0.0 in both frontend and backend.

Explicitly mapping ports in .replit to expose 8080 as 80.

Testing Webview ports (3000, 8080) which work locally.


Question:
How can I correctly configure my Replit deployment to ensure the application works on the production domain (https://my-app.replit.app) and properly routes traffic between frontend (Vite) and backend (Python)?


In the Deployment "App" within Replit, did you add your production domain and related configurations to the Settings of the related deployment? This caused me some visibility errors until I corrected the CNAME, A, and TXT records.
